# DragMouse command in Pywinauto

Tags: python, copy, mouse, drag, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto and have to copy a word from an application which doesn't retrieve any values on `PrintControlIdentifiers()` command. My idea is to drag mouse from the start of the text till the end of the text by using `DragMouse` command and then use `Ctrl + C` command.

I used the below command for my application:

```
window1.DragMouse(button='left', pressed='',press_coords=(256,0),release_coords=(256,800))
```

But this isn't working and not throwing any error message as well. Please let me know where can I find more examples on DragMouse.

Comment: Have you tried `DragMouseInput` instead?

Comment: What about (Tab if needed) Ctrl+A then Ctrl+C?

Comment: @Vasily : DragMouseInput is not working as well .After going through few of your other blogs , the question I have now is ,"Is DragMouse or DragMouseInput " can be used for highlight(select) the text ?

Comment: @Swapy : If at all the word which I want to copy is the only text in the screen , then it would be a good option , but I have to choose a particular text.

Comment: `DragMouse*` methods are used for edit box text highlighting in unit tests. But your control seems very specific. I'll try to suggest a workaround using `TypeKeys`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `DragMouseInput` doesn't work for you, I can suggest a workaround. The code might look like that (just a prototype, not tested):

```
 from pywinauto import clipboard

 app.Window.Control.TypeKeys('^a^c') # Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C
 full_str = clipboard.GetData()
 start_index = full_str.find(substring)
 app.Window.Control.TypeKeys('{HOME}{RIGHT %d}+{RIGHT %d}^c' % (start_index, len(substring)))
 # ^ is Ctrl, + is Shift
```

This approach doesn't depend on coordinates that is more resistant to screen resolution change.

To navigate to the control (if it's not in keyboard focus) you may use `{TAB}` key alias (BTW, `{TAB 3} == {TAB}{TAB}{TAB}`).

Comment: Vasily , thanks .Unfortunately , Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C is not copying the entire text from the application .However , I have tried to Tab to the particular string and used your above code by replacing %d  with numbers.It is not working .Can you please explain ,how TypeKeys('{HOME}{RIGHT 4}^{RIGHT 4}^c would work ,so that I can workaround to fix the problem.Your code helped me to optimize my other issues .

Comment: If your control is focused for keyboard input, you may  `Home` key to set the keyboard cursor at the position 0. Then you press right arrow to navigate for several positions to the right direction. Then you hold `Shift` (sorry, I meant `Shift` that is `%` not `^`) and press right arrow to select necessary part of the text. I've fixed my answer to press `Shift`.

Comment: Hi Vasily , thanks a lot for such a great idea !By the way Shift is '+' and Alt is '%'

Comment: Ops, sorry. Corrected the answer. :)

Comment: Vasily , I am using Clipboard , however , it is weird to notice that yet times it is working fine but sometimes , it is throwing me the following error: pywintypes.error: (5, 'OpenClipboard', 'Access is denied.')
Is there any other suggestion ?

Comment: It uses standard win32clipboard. I can suggest only several attempts calling `GetData()` with `WaitUntilPasses()` function from `pywinauto.timings` module. Hope it will help.